# how can i increase the performance of SQL?(sub query is used)

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance

```
SELECT contents.*, 

(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM comments
WHERE comments.scrap_id = contents.org_scrap_id) AS comment_count

FROM contents
ORDER BY comment_count
```

this is my intention. but it makes very long waits.

how can i increase the performance of this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase the performance by creating an index on `comments(scrap_id)`:

```
create index comments_scrap_id on comments(scrap_id);
```

You could also try phrasing this as a `join` and `group by`:

```
SELECT co.*, count(com.scrap_id) as comment_count
FROM contents co left outer join
     comments com
     on co.org_scrap_id = com.scrap_id
GROUP BY co.id
---------^ or whatever the appropriate `id` is for this table
ORDER BY comment_count;
```

But the index is likely to give better performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your query using join,but for performance an explain plan is needed,you are using a correlated subquery which will run for each row in contents table and can reduce the performance of query, for below query you need an index for `scrap_id` from comments table and `org_scrap_id` from contents table if its not a primary key

```
SELECT c.*, COUNT(cm.scrap_id) comment_count
LEFT JOIN comments cm
  ON cm.scrap_id = c.org_scrap_id
FROM contents c
GROUP BY c.org_scrap_id
ORDER BY comment_count
```

Comment: its not necessary to add all columns into GROUP BY clause.? also count(*) should be ambiguous here.

Comment: @llesh Patel sorry i didn't get your point related all columns in group by i have mentioned only c.org_scrap_id

Comment: When you write c.* that means you are selecting all the rows of table contents which has not only org_scrap_id but may be many others. so if you use COUNT(*) and only do GROUP BY c.org_scrap_id than it will give error like  "column Name must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function" .  isn't it?

Comment: While I agree with the requirement for the index on `scrap_id`, I don't see how this query will improve on the original.

Comment: @MarcusAdams in my answer i gave the reason for the usage of corelated subquery which will be executed for every row contents table therefore i provide the solution to use join so with help of index the performance will be much better but the real picture of performance can be seen by the explain plan for both queries

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use joins which would be faster compared to what you are doing now

```
SELECT contents.*, count(comments.scrap_id) 
from contents 
left outer join comments on comments.scrap_id=contents.scrap_id
group by comments.scrap_id
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try doing it this way and check if it makes any difference in performance.

```
  SELECT Conts.* , 
       Comts.scrap_id_COUNT
  FROM
       contents Conts INNER JOIN( SELECT scrap_id , 
                                         COUNT(1) AS scrap_id_COUNT
                                    FROM comments
                                    GROUP BY scrap_id
                                ) AS Comts
       ON Conts.org_scrap_id = Comts.scrap_id
  ORDER BY Comts.scrap_id_COUNT
```